# CGAL AABB tree do_intersect floating point error

Tags: cgal, aabb

I am using CGAL for a project of mine. I create a AABB tree out of a mesh file (.off). First I extract Polyhedron from my mesh, then I get the triangles and finally I insert them in the tree.
All of this went smoothly.

The problem is when I use the **do_intersect** function of the tree.
Given two points, A and B, I would like to know if the ray or segment connecting the two insersect with something.

Most of the time this works properly, sometimes I get the **floating point error**. 'sometimes' means with a very few subsets of points.

Is there a reason for this?

Here there is a snippet of my code:

```
glm::vec3 pointA, pointB; // assume this are filled with some values
// the elements inside points above are floats.
Point_3 pA(pointA.x, pointA.y, pointA.z);
Point_3 pB(pointB.x, pointB.y, pointB.z);
Segment segment_query(pA, pB);
my_tree->do_intersect(segment_query); // here sometimes crashes
```

Before anybody asks *pointB* is a specific point on the surface of the mesh and it does not give any problems with most of points so I would assume the error is not related to it. Instead *pointA* is somewhere in the space.

Thank you for you answers.

Comment: what kernel are you using? you need one with exact predicates here like for example `CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel`.

Comment: Here it is, just the same you pointed out:
`typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;`

Comment: do you have some degenerate triangles in your input mesh?

Comment: I don't think so, can you give me some example? Or some way to check it?
I am using a manifold mesh.

Comment: Try running your code in debug (i.e. with assertions ON) and you will get a message in case of degenerate triangles.

Comment: I checked the triangles, none of them are degenerate.

Comment: In that case, I'd be interested in getting a minimal example showing the pb (a segment and a mesh should be sufficient I guess)

Comment: I solved my issues avoiding to query the AABB tree in parallel and with few changes in my code.
The points I was referring above where generated randomly and the same point sometimes triggered the error, others didn't.
Needless to say now I generate points in a more proper way and I don't get the error anymore.